# Find out who stopped a process (7zip)

Tags: windows

How could I find out who stopped a process? It was a 7zip process making a backup and someone or something quitted it.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I find out who stopped a process?

As long as you do not use extensive auditing (do some research on "security auditing" in Windows), this will stay a mystery.